# NSTextView in NSPersistentDocument doesn't update dirty flag until loses first responder

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nstextview

I have an `NSTextView` in an `NSPersistentDocument` window. I bind the text field's contents to a "binary data" Core Data field, but when I type text into the text view, the document's title bar doesn't say "Edited" until the text view loses focus. Thus, if I quit after making an edit, the new data isn't saved.

If I pass the `NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption` flag to the text view binding, "Edited" appears immediately, but performance really suffers in long documents.

How do I let Core Data know that there are unsaved changes without actually assigning all the text data on every change?

(This question is like "[Binded NSTextField doesn't update the entity until it lose the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580992/binded-nstextfield-doesnt-update-the-entity-until-it-lose-the-focus/15465501#15465501)" except I can't use `NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption` because it makes editing operations very slow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible as far as i understood.
When you assign the changes to a property of a NSManagnedObject, CoreData manage to diry state (and the undo stuff) for you. If you just try to change the diry without the data a potential save operation will not work.

Take a look into "[The Document Architecture Provides Undo Support for Free](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH5-SW28)" how the dirty state and the undo support are implemented.

If you have really large text documents, i suggest you should not store them in a CoreData property. As you can read in "[Incremental Data Reading and Writing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/AdvancedTopics/AdvancedTopics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH7-SW25)" i suggest to store the text in a separate file and use a NSFileWrapper. At least I use this solution for my application.

This is btw. what CoreData itself suggest [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW1) "...It is better, however, if you are able to store BLOBs as resources on the filesystem, and to maintain links (such as URLs or paths) to those resources. You can then load a BLOB as and when necessary"

I don't know what kind of text you have in your NSTextView but you was taking about "long documents".

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass your "`NSTextView`", you can catch the ["`insertText:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/insertText%3a) method and then as soon as a character is typed, set the ["document Edited" flag of the document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setDocumentEdited%3a) without the heavy duty (and CPU intensive) binding you're doing.

Comment: `setDocumentEdited:` is an NSWindow method, not an NSDocument method. It's called automatically by the document when you update the document's change count; a document-based app should never need to send the window `setDocumentEdited:` directly. (In fact, I wonder if the description for `setDocumentEdited:` is older than NSDocument.)

Comment: So you're also suggesting adding a hook to update the Core Data model by hand when a save is triggered? Would Core Data know that a save is required because the window's `documentEdited` flag is set?